# Django ModelFormSet with Google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I'm using Django with google app engine. I'm using the google furnished django app engine helper project.

I'm attempting to create a Django modelformset like this:

```
#MyModel inherits from BaseModel    
MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.MyModel)
```

However, it's failing with this error:

> 'ModelOptions' object has no attribute 'fields'

Apparently modelformset_factory() is expecting MyModel to implement a 'fields' accessor.

Anybody successfully used a modelformset with GAE datastore? Or is this a fundamental incompatibility between Django and GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a fundamental incompatibility between Django and GAE, because they do not share the same interface for their models.  The django helper does not include a patch for the modelformsets, but django-nonrel probably does, or will eventually.

Since the google team does not spend much time on the django helper any more, you are probably better off looking at django-nonrel http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel unless you want to patch the helper yourself.